# Update an issue to redmine server using Rest API C# and getting 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, redmine

I'm newbie in building redmine client by Rest API. I'm trying to update an issue to redmine server and server response 500 Internal Server Error.
Here is my production log.

```
 Started PUT "/redmine/issues/7.xml" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-21 16:13:38 +0700
Processing by IssuesController#update as XML
  Parameters: {"issue"=>{"subject"=>"Stop test close", "notes"=>"My note", "private_notes"=>"false", "description"=>"Updated description", "is_private"=>"false", "project_id"=>"1", "priority_id"=>"4", "status_id"=>"2", "tracker_id"=>"2", "assigned_to_id"=>"1", "estimated_hours"=>"30", "done_ratio"=>"10", "start_date"=>"2015-10-12", "due_date"=>"2015-10-12", "updated_on"=>"2015-10-19", "uploads"=>nil, "custom_fields"=>nil}, "id"=>"7"}
  Current user: user (id=1)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms (ActiveRecord: 8.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `inject' for nil:NilClass):
  lib/plugins/acts_as_customizable/lib/acts_as_customizable.rb:54:in `custom_fields='
  app/models/issue.rb:372:in `assign_attributes_with_project_and_tracker_first'
  app/models/issue.rb:495:in `safe_attributes='
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:397:in `update_issue_from_params'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:176:in `update'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

Please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: No, I'm not. I think some field has null value so it make this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the bug. In this case, the server raise error some thing null and it can't updates to database. The server didn't tell what error on that then I check the production.log. I found the solution that "'uploads'=>nil, 'custom_fields'=>nil" was null then we should remove or make it not null. So the problem was fixed. Thank for your attend!

Answer (score -1):

If you update via email with attachments, just modify 'attachments' table with default description row set to '' not null ;)